# Why is the API response time for Audio Stream Recognition so slow?

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-speech

I am using very similar code to [Google's example](https://cloud.google.com/speech/docs/streaming-recognize#performing_streaming_speech_recognition_on_an_audio_stream) for performing speech recognition on an Audio stream using the Node.js client library.

The API is parsing my audio correctly, but I find myself waiting 30-45 seconds before I get a response. Considering how snappy the [demo](https://cloud.google.com/speech/) is, this doesn't seem right. Is there something I am configuring incorrectly on my end?

I've tried writing to a local file instead just to make sure the audio is coming through clearly, and the recording seems fine.

Thanks for any help you can give!

```
import record from 'node-record-lpcm16';
import Speech from '@google-cloud/speech';


function streamToParser(){
  const speech = Speech();
  const request = {
    config: {
      encoding: 'LINEAR16',
      sampleRateHertz: 16000,
      languageCode: 'en-US',
    },
    interimResults: true,
  };

  const recognizeStream = speech.createRecognizeStream(request)
  .on('error', console.error)
  .on('data', (data) => {
    console.log(data.results)
  });

  record
  .start({
    sampleRate: 16000,
    threshold: .6,
    verbose: true,
    silence: '5.0'
  })
  .on('error', console.error)
  .pipe(recognizeStream)

  console.log('Google is listening...')
};



streamToParser();
```

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out - I wasn't configuring `Speech` with auth credentials, so my requests must have been deprioritized. Here's the config that fixed it, as per the instructions [here](https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-node/#/docs/google-cloud/v0.55.0/google-cloud):

```
const speech = Speech({
    projectId: 'my project ID from the Google Cloud dev console',
    keyFilename: 'path/to/keyfile.json', // that I generated/downloaded from the Google Cloud dev console
});
```

To create a `json` keyfile, follow the steps outlined [here](https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-node/#/docs/google-cloud/v0.55.0/guides/authentication) in the "On Your Own Server" section.